# flutter android connecting real device this error is displayed

Tags: android, flutter

```
W/RenderThread(24681): type=1400 audit(0.0:169510): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=14875 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c80,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Comment: Hi @KVSR. Could you please add more info about what you're trying to achieve and what's going wrong. The error itself is not a problem.

Comment: I am trying login app with phonenumber and

Comment: and the it is not working